# javascript redirect doesn't work

Tags: javascript, redirect, cookies

I am trying to add an age verification popup to my website. It needs to remember cookies so that it doesn't ask everytime someone clicks on a different page. The cookies seem to work fine, but the redirect link doesn't work. When the popup pops up and you hit no/cancel it doesn't redirect to Google. It just goes to the page. Also, the "var answer = confirm('Are you 18 or older?');" piece doesn't seem to be giving me a Yes or No option, just an Ok and Cancel. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

var ofAge = getCookie("ofAge");
if (ofAge != "true") {
    var answer = confirm('Are you 18 or older?');
    if (answer = true) {
        setCookie("ofAge", "true", 1);
    } else {
        window.location = "http://www.google.com";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: `answer = true` <--- assignment vs comparison.

Comment: There is no way to make the built-in `confirm()` function use "Yes" / "No" buttons, it always uses "OK" / "Cancel".

Answer (score 0):

> When the popup pops up and you hit no/cancel it doesn't redirect to
>   Google.

Change:

```
if (answer = true) {...}
```

to this:

```
if (answer) {...}
```

Your original code was assigning (that's what `=` does in Javascript), not comparing.  Since the result of the assignment is always `true`, your `if` statement would always evaluate to truthy and thus you would never hit the `else` clause.  Plus, since you know you have a boolean, you can just do `if (answer)` just fine - no need to specify the `true` part.

---

> Also, the "var answer = confirm('Are you 18 or older?');" piece
>   doesn't seem to be giving me a Yes or No option, just an Ok and
>   Cancel. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

The `confirm()` function always displays "OK" and "Cancel".  It doesn't use "Yes" and "No".  That is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Check your comparison operator. It should be "==" not "=".
    ie,

```
var answer = confirm('Are you 18 or older?');
if (answer == true) {
setCookie("ofAge","true",1);
} else {
     window.location="http://www.google.com";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Problem #0: Cross Origin

You're redirecting to `http://google.com`. Because of security issues, in JavaScript, you can only really deal with your own domain. Redirect to a page on your website

## Problem #1: `=` is not `==`

This is the cruft of your problem. You're assigning answer to `true`, not reading it's value. Use `if(answer == true)` or just `if(answer)`

## Problem #2: Confirm

You cannot change the text on buttons on the `confirm()` dialog (or any dialog for that matter). What I would suggest you do is either of the following

**Solution 2.0**: Say "You must be 18 or older to continue". Instead of asking "Are you over 18?", we rephrase the question to be answered by an `Ok` or `Cancel`

**Solution 2.1**: Ask them their age, and compare:

```
var age = prompt("How old are you?")
if (age => 18) {...} else {...}
```

Hope I could be helpful!